# XSLT to merge two xml

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

I have two xml responses as below.

response1.xml

```
      <UploadFileResponse xmlns="http://SharepointTask">
         <UploadFileResult>
            <taskData>
               <TaskID>47</TaskID>
               <TaskState>Completed</TaskState>
            </taskData>
         </UploadFileResult>
      </UploadFileResponse>
```

response2.xml

```
      <UploadFileResponse xmlns="http://SharepointTask">
         <UploadFileResult>
            <taskData>
               <TaskID>48</TaskID>
               <TaskState>Completed</TaskState>
            </taskData>
         </UploadFileResult>
      </UploadFileResponse>
```

Now, I want to apply XSLT and get the output as below

```
      <UploadFileResponse xmlns="http://SharepointTask">
         <UploadFileResult>
            <taskData>
               <TaskID>47</TaskID>
               <TaskState>Completed</TaskState>
            </taskData>
          <taskData>
               <TaskID>48</TaskID>
               <TaskState>Completed</TaskState>
            </taskData>
         </UploadFileResult>
      </UploadFileResponse>
```

I m not sure as to how to transform these two xmls and get the specific node out of it. I have basic idea of XSLT and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use document to read in files. http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_document.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the document() function to import in your xsl stylesheet a second xml file to parse (over the one that it's linked to stylesheet).

You ca do for example:

```
<xsl:variable name="response2"><xsl:value-of select="'response2.xml'"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="document($response2)//UploadFileResponse/UploadFileResult/taskData/TaskID"/>
```

This example will output 48.